# C project (POS) - Displaying payment change error

Tags: c

I have a C project below. Its kinda POS. My problem is displaying the customer's payment change. Almost done with the system, just that change displaying part. I am having runtime error running this code. Hope you could help me with this one. I still have documentation to finish. Thanks in advance :)

```
int Purchase(){
addon=0;
strcpy(addonC,"00");
system("cls");
printf("\t############################################\n");
printf("\t#                                          #\n");
printf("\t#                BEVERAGES                 #\n");
printf("\t#                            Reg   Large   #\n");
printf("\t#   [a] Banana MilkTea     - 130    145    #\n");
printf("\t#   [b] Nagoya             - 160    175    #\n");
printf("\t#   [c] Hazelnut Smoothie  - 150    165    #\n");
printf("\t#   [d] Vanilla Matcha     - 130    145    #\n");
printf("\t#                                          #\n");
printf("\t############################################\n");
printf("\n\n\tChoice: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c",&choice);
printf("\tBeverage: ");

switch(choice){
    case 'a':
        printf("\tBanana MilkTea");
        strcpy(Beverage,Item1);
        cost=130;
        break;
    case 'b':
        printf("\tNagoya");
        strcpy(Beverage,Item2);
        cost=160;
        break;
    case 'c':
        printf("Hazelnut Smoothie");
        strcpy(Beverage,Item3);
        cost=150;
        break;
    case 'd':
        printf("Vanila Matcha");
        strcpy(Beverage,Item4);
        cost=130;
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid Choice. Please try again.");
        Purchase(tAmt1);
        break;
}
do{
    temp=0;
    printf("\n\t----------------------------\n");
    printf("\t[1]Regular,[2]Large\n\tChoose size: ");
    fflush(stdin); scanf("%i",&size);

    switch(size){
        case 1:
            printf("\n\tItem: Regular %s",Beverage);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\n\tItem: Large %s",Beverage);
            break;
        default:
            printf("\tInvalid size. Please try again");
            break;
    }
    if(size==1 || size==2)
        break;
}while(size!=1 || size !=2);

if(size==2){
    cost=cost+15;
    printf("\n\tCost: %i",cost);
}
else{
    printf("\n\tCost: %i",cost);
}

printf("\n\tAddons? [Y]Yes/[N]No: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c",&choice);
if(choice=='y' || choice=='Y'){
    do{
    //  system("cls");
            printf("\n\t############################\n");
            printf("\t#                          #\n");
            printf("\t#        ADD-ONS           #\n");
            printf("\t#   [a] Crystals      30   #\n");
            printf("\t#   [b] Small Pearls  25   #\n");
            printf("\t#   [c] Big Pearls    30   #\n");
            printf("\t#   [d] Taro          40   #\n");
            printf("\t#                          #\n");
            printf("\t############################\n");

            printf("\tEnter your add-on: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &add);
        switch(add){
            case 'a':
                addon=30;
                printf("\tAdd Crystals");
                strcpy(addonC,"Crystals");
                break;
            case 'b':
                addon=25;
                printf("\tAdd Small_Pearls");
                strcpy(addonC,"Small_Pearls");
                break;
            case 'c':
                addon=30;
                printf("\tAdd Big_Pearls");
                strcpy(addonC,"Big_Pearls");
                break;
            case 'd':
                addon=40;
                printf("\tAdd Taro");
                strcpy(addonC,"Taro");
                break;
            default:
                system("cls");
                printf("\tInvalid addon. \nPlease try again.");
                break;
        }
        if(add=='a' || add=='b' || add=='c' || add=='d')
            break;

    }while(add!='a' || add!='b' || add!='c' || add!='d');
}
else{

}

FILE *f_sales;
f_sales=fopen("sales.txt","a+");
fprintf(f_sales,"%i %s %i %s %i %i\n",date,Beverage,size,addonC,cost,addon);
subTotal=cost+addon;
printf("\n\tSubtotal: %i",subTotal);
tAmt1+=subTotal;
printf("\n\n\tTOTAL AMOUNT: %i",tAmt1);
printf("\n\tpress any key to continue...");
getch();
fclose(f_sales);
do{
    printf("\n\n\t*****************\n\n\tAnother purchase? [Y]Yes/[N]No: ");    
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    if(choice=='y' || choice=='Y'){
        Purchase();
    }
    else if(choice=='n' || choice=='N'){
        printf("\tCustomer's Payment: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%i",&cPay);
    //  Total=tAmt1;
        printf("\tCustomer's Change: %i",cPay-tAmt1);
        printf("\tGo back to main menu? [Y]Yes | [N]No: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&choice);
        if(choice=='y' || choice=='Y')
            SaleMenu();

        else{
            printf("\tHave a good day!\n");
            getch();
            printf("\tProgram will now Exit...");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("\n\tInvalid choice. Try again.");
        system("cls");
    }

}while(choice!='n' || choice=='N' || choice=='y' || choice=='Y');
//return tAmt1;
```

}

Comment: What does the error say? In what part of Your program does it emerge? We don't have crystal balls... :-)

Comment: displayng customer's change:

    printf("\tCustomer's Change: %i",cPay-tAmt1);

Comment: Your code is not complete.

Comment: Yeah, its too long actually displaying the whole code. This is the function that Im having problem with.

Comment: its compiling but im having runtime error in the part when the system needs to display the amount of customer's change.

Comment: Condition of the loop is funny

Comment: Lol BLUEPIXY. I dont need your criticism. Thats all Ive got. Im not professional. Im just a student. I need your answer if you have any. :)

Comment: What kind of runtime error do you get [Division by zero, Segmentation fault]?

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is not a good thing to do I think.

Comment: it stop working on the part when i input the customer's payment.

Comment: How is `addonC` defined?

Comment: hi all,ive posted the whole code that you can be able to compile and run.

Comment: Jongware,addonC is the choice of add ons customer have chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is at

```
  scanf("%i",cPay);
```

It may better to give the pointer, as you are doing everywhere else...

```
  scanf("%i",&cPay);
```

I would also suggest to use `%d` instead of `%i`. But if one of your costumers only knows hexadecimal digits, keep `%i` !

Bye,

Francis

Comment: oh my gulay...im very careless,,you hit it right.. thanks so much